# Python: create dictionary using dict() with integer keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, integer, key

In Python, I see people creating dictionaries like this:

```
d = dict( one = 1, two = 2, three = 3 )
```

What if my keys are integers? When I try this:

```
d = dict (1 = 1, 2 = 2, 3 = 3 )
```

I get an error. Of course I could do this:

```
d = { 1:1, 2:2, 3:3 }
```

which works fine, but my main question is this: is there a way to set *integer* keys using the dict() function/constructor?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Yes, but not with that version of the constructor.  You can do this:

```
>>> dict([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

There are several different ways to make a dict.  As [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), "providing keyword arguments [...] only works for keys that are valid Python identifiers."

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. There's an easy and visually appealing way to make a dictionary `d = dict(one=1, two=2)` but if your keys are NOT valid Python identifiers, you are forced to use much less simple looking syntax. :(

Comment: @Sindyr: There is an easy and appealing way.  It's `{1:2, 3:4}`.

Comment: Yes, I had that in my main example, I just found the equal syntax of `1 = 1` even more so.

Comment: @Sindyr, i do not find an assignment of the form `1 = 2` meaningful or appealing.

Comment: How can I add new values to this dict?

Comment: @Mr.rk You have two choices: 1) merge an existing dict with your new dict content ({**{1:2, 3:4}, **{5:6, 3:7}}). This will replace existing keys from rhs to lhs. 2) Use list comprehension to convert the dict, manipulate (add/remove key/value pairs) as a list of tuples, and restore into the dict ([(k,v) for k,v in mydict.items()]...dict([k1,v1), (k2,v2),..(kn,vn)]) )

Comment: Is there no other way to simply add an entry to the dictionary with integer as a key? Wow...

Comment: @Yamo93: Sure there is.  You can just do `my_dict[1] = "whatever"`.

Answer (score 15):

There are also these 'ways':

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(range(1, 4))
{1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
>>> dict(zip(range(1, 4), range(1, 4)))
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

Comment: Heyo, didn't know of the fromkeys class method. That's useful! In fact, just today I was working on a multi-source merge, and I'm iterating over the set of keys from multiple sources, because they all can have distinct items, but the keys are dicts and objects that resolve to instances of a specific class. Thanks, @aivar-paalberg!

Answer (score -4):

```
a = dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)
```

Providing keyword arguments as in this example only works for keys that are valid Python identifiers. Otherwise, any valid keys can be used.