# How would you create a dictionary with integer keys and values of 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How would you create a dictionary in python, which would look a bit like this:

```
{1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, ...}
```

for a specific number of iterations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544835/python-create-dictionary-using-dict-with-integer-keys[Check your Answer Through This Link][1]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Creating a dictionary with same values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977730/creating-a-dictionary-with-same-values)

Answer (score 8):

Use [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys)

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(range(1, 5), 0)
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
my_dict = {i:0 for i in range(1,x)}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
dict(enumerate([0]*10,1))

{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0}
```